A show about two blonde teenage geniuses
The series is about 2 teenagers, a boy and a girl, both of them are blonde; they are both geniuses I think, and the girl is evil.  I don't know many details, but I think the girl invents destructive stuff, trying to destroy the boy. The girl's name is Elizabeth I think .

It's very generic details. Please add more detail so that anyone can identify it otherwise it will be closed in this current situation.

Posting a possible match, but yes, more details (like year, country\language, animated\live action etc.) would really help us out.

What kind of geniuses? Was this movie sci-fi, fantasy or something else altogether?

Possibly the Australian show Wicked Science from 2004-2006 about two blonde teens who both suddenly become geniuses and battle eachother with scientific inventions:

Toby Johnson is regular easy-going student struggling with homework and girls. Elizabeth Hawke is the Teacher's pet. Nobody at school likes her and the only person she likes is Toby. One day they get hit by a ray—a unique magnetic pulse that changes everything. Suddenly they're both scientific geniuses. Seems like a wild situation for any 15-year-old. Toby doesn't know how to control the gift, and he's not easy with it. But Elizabeth revels in her newfound power. She wants to dominate the school, using her gift as the ultimate weapon for success and power.

It aired on the Disney Channel (and Disney Channel Asia). Here's the show's trailer:




you got it bro  thank you
